# How to calculate fft of large size data ,avoid memory exhausted?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, fftw

Calculate `fft` with 16GB memory,cause memory exhausted.

```
print(data_size)
freqs, times, spec_arr = signal.spectrogram(data, fs=samp_rate,nfft=1024,return_onesided=False,axis=0,scaling='spectrum',mode='magnitude')
```

Output as below:

```
537089518
Killed
```

How to calculate fft of large size data ,with existing python package?

Comment: `signal.spectrogram` doesn’t compute the FFT. It uses the FFT internally, but the result is not the same as the FFT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general solution is to do that yourself. 1D FFTs can be split in smaller ones thanks to the well-known [Cooley–Tukey FFT algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) and multidimentional decomposition. For more information about this strategy, please read [The Design and Implementation of FFTW3](https://math.mit.edu/%7Estevenj/papers/FrigoJo05.pdf). You can do the operation in [virtually mapped memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) so to do that more easily. Some library/package like the FFTW enable you to relatively-easily perform fast in-place FFTs. You may need to write your own Python package or to use Cython so not to allocate additional memory that is not memory mapped.

One alternative solution is to save your data in HDF5 (for example using [h5py](https://www.h5py.org/), and then use [out_of_core_fft](https://github.com/moble/out_of_core_fft) and then read again the file. But, be aware that this package is a bit old and appear not to be maintained anymore.

Comment: Big thanks.what I tried with `torch`:`t=torch.from_numpy(data)`, `f=torch.fft.fft(t)`.I am not sure whether that's a correct way,because the result has big difference.

Comment: I can't tell for `torch` as I never used it. Note that some library renormalize results (AFAIK using a simple multiplication by a factor) while other do not. This could explain the difference. It appears `torch` does not normalize the results by default (while people often need it).

Comment: If I don't care about time,how about enlarge `swap` to make fft consume?

Comment: This can be a simple solution indeed, but this require root privilege. It also reserve a fixed amount of space on the disk that should be cleverly chosen. In addition, this is OS dependent. On Windows the swap-file already use a variable amount of space. AFAIK, on Linux, you should avoid allocating much more than the amount of RAM, otherwise the whole system can become very very slow (due to trashing). See: https://serverfault.com/questions/17718 . Note this only work on your target machine (you can hardly ask people to do this to run your program).